# Has anyone figured out a great way to run accurate conversion reporting?

Tags: analytics

I don't have a lot of latitude in changing our platform (we are currently using KISSmetrics and Google Analytics) so if someone has a solution on those platforms that would be ideal, but I would like to know if there is another analytics platform that does a good job with this problem out of the box.

Google Analytics allows me to segment on new users, but I don't really trust the accuracy of the conversion metrics. Additionally I am mostly interested in a metric we don't track in GA (payments) bc most people are on a trial first and we currently don't have any kind of confirmation page for payments that would uniquely show when a payment was made.

KISSmetrics does a good job on accuracy of reporting but doesn't have a "first time visitor" event out of the box. When I run conversion to payment stats it includes lots of people that are just returning to use the product (SaaS product). What I am overlooking.

To be clear, there are ways to get at this information but it requires that I download the data into an excel spreadsheet and run the analysis there. I would prefer to just be able to run a report. Would save a ton of time on analyzing a [test I am running](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/11/20/testing-home-page-kissmetrics/).

Comment: So you need to differentiate between the paying customer sessions and the free trial sessions and then run your conversion analysis on the paying customer segment?

Comment: Not only that but I need to be able to tell if that person has been to the site before. I don't want existing users watering down results